# Crockpot recipes using soda pop

Tags: substitutions

Can diet soda be substituted for regular soda in recipes such as BBQ ribs, pork roasts, etc?

I do not know if different results will occur when heating diet pop for any length of time.  I do know that regular soda pop works.

Comment: This is just opinion, but I find the taste of diet sodas disgusting. So my answer would be that you can substitute, but at least one person would find the results inedible.

Comment: This is interesting. Regular pop is included partially for the flavor but also very much for the sugar. I don't know what artificial sweeteners will do when heated and condensed. Do they create a syrupy texture?

Answer (score 8):

[Aspartame is not heat stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspartame).

> Aspartame is less suitable for baking than other sweeteners, because it breaks down when heated and loses much of its sweetness.

Some sodas use other artificial sweeteners.
 You'll need to look up the particular sweetener that's in your diet pop of choice, and see if it's heat stable.

Comment: I usually see soda included in BBQ-style recipes where you want to form a glaze of some kind.  Beyond sweetness, I'd think sugar would greatly contribute to the mouthfeel of the finished sauce.  So this is probably a bad idea for a few different reasons.